# Sending json data to android from WordPress plugin

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I am completely new to wordpress development. I have a website in WordPress. I want to send the data from my database table to an android app. I am confused about how to make the api from wordpress so that I can call the api link from my android app to get the data in json format.

I need someone's help badly!

Comment: Have you seen this plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) ?
Or you need take data from the specific plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't seen this plugin yet. So with this plugin I can send the data in json format from my database tables?

Comment: Almost yes, also take a look the [refference](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/)  for that plugin. If you need to add to json some custom field you need to add some features to your theme.
I also advise  you to look at the example how it works on YouTube.

Comment: actually what I wanted to is very simple. I want an api from where I can get the table data in json format so that I can use in my android app.

Comment: This plugin is what you need. Try it. There are many examples of its use in the web